# how to map null json response to empty string in kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I have data modal which i am using to parse json response from api:

```
internal class ImageResponse(
    @SerializedName("ID")
    val id: String,
    @SerializedName("URL")
    val url: String
)
```

The problem I'm facing is sometime in response key `@SerializedName("URL")` is not present.

So in data modal value of url is `null`.

Can you suggest way so it will empty instead of `null`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible with Gson: https://proandroiddev.com/most-elegant-way-of-using-gson-kotlin-with-default-values-and-null-safety-b6216ac5328c. Is it possible to switch to a different JSON serialization library?

Comment: this is legacy project, difficult at this time.

Comment: Maybe this will work for you in this case: https://proandroiddev.com/safe-parsing-kotlin-data-classes-with-gson-4d560fe3cdd2